# How to make profile plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, profile

The data set is lay out in long format and has some missing values, which has 4 columns,
the 1st column is "id",
the 2nd column is binary variable "condition",
the 3rd column is variable "time",
the 4th variable is "outcome,

Now, I want to create a profile plot with R, which is displayed in SPSS in the attached. I know how to create it using SPSS, but I don't know how to do this in R. (The links to display the pictures created by SPSS are listed in the end of this post)

The original data set is structured as follows,

```r
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 
102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 
104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 
107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 
123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 126, 126, 126, 
126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 
130, 130, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 132, 
132, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 134, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 
138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 140, 140, 140, 
140, 140, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202, 202, 202, 203, 
203, 203, 203, 203, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 205, 205, 205, 205, 
205, 206, 206, 206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 208, 208, 
208, 208, 208, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 
212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 
214, 214, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 217, 
217, 217, 217, 217, 218, 218, 218, 218, 218, 219, 219, 219, 219, 
219, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 302, 302, 
302, 302, 302, 303, 303, 303, 303, 303, 304, 304, 304, 304, 304, 
305, 305, 305, 305, 305), label = "Subject #", format.spss = "F11.0", display_width = 11L), 
    condition = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "CT=1 BT=0", format.spss = "F11.0", display_width = 11L), 
    time = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    outcome = structure(c(3.09104245335832, 2.89037175789616, 
    2.07944154167984, 2.30258509299405, 2.63905732961526, 3.58351893845611, 
    2.94443897916644, 2.19722457733622, 2.83321334405622, 2.99573227355399, 
    3.13549421592915, 2.89037175789616, 2.99573227355399, 2.70805020110221, 
    2.30258509299405, 3.43398720448515, 3.04452243772342, 2.56494935746154, 
    2.484906649788, 1.38629436111989, 3.25809653802148, 2.83321334405622, 
    2.484906649788, 2.56494935746154, 2.77258872223978, 3.55534806148941, 
    2.484906649788, 2.70805020110221, 1.38629436111989, 2.63905732961526, 
    3.49650756146648, 3.04452243772342, 2.70805020110221, 2.56494935746154, 
    2.484906649788, 3.2188758248682, 3.2188758248682, 3.09104245335832, 
    3.09104245335832, 3.09104245335832, 3.17805383034795, 3.17805383034795, 
    2.56494935746154, 2.30258509299405, 1.38629436111989, 3.13549421592915, 
    2.77258872223978, 2.77258872223978, NA, NA, 3.17805383034795, 
    3.17805383034795, 2.70805020110221, 2.63905732961526, 2.19722457733622, 
    3.3322045101752, 2.19722457733622, 2.39789527279837, 0.693147180559945, 
    1.94591014905531, 3.09104245335832, 2.56494935746154, 2.07944154167984, 
    1.6094379124341, 2.07944154167984, 3.25809653802148, 2.39789527279837, 
    2.39789527279837, 2.56494935746154, 2.56494935746154, 3.36729582998647, 
    3.36729582998647, 3.17805383034795, 3.17805383034795, NA, 
    2.99573227355399, 3.04452243772342, 3.2188758248682, 3.3322045101752, 
    3.3322045101752, 3.3322045101752, 2.89037175789616, 2.39789527279837, 
    2.30258509299405, 3.29583686600433, 3.36729582998647, 3.13549421592915, 
    3.04452243772342, 3.04452243772342, 3.13549421592915, 3.2188758248682, 
    2.83321334405622, 2.30258509299405, 2.484906649788, 1.94591014905531, 
    3.49650756146648, 3.09104245335832, 2.83321334405622, 1.6094379124341, 
    3.09104245335832, 3.49650756146648, 2.70805020110221, 2.63905732961526, 
    2.56494935746154, 2.19722457733622, 3.25809653802148, 2.83321334405622, 
    2.63905732961526, 2.39789527279837, NA, 3.29583686600433, 
    2.39789527279837, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 1.94591014905531, 
    3.52636052461616, 3.55534806148941, 3.43398720448515, 3.43398720448515, 
    3.43398720448515, 3.3322045101752, 3.25809653802148, 2.89037175789616, 
    3.09104245335832, NA, 3.29583686600433, 3.25809653802148, 
    3.17805383034795, 3.3322045101752, NA, 3.17805383034795, 
    2.56494935746154, 2.07944154167984, 2.19722457733622, 0, 
    3.40119738166216, 3.29583686600433, 3.40119738166216, 3.40119738166216, 
    3.43398720448515, 3.2188758248682, 2.77258872223978, 1.79175946922805, 
    1.79175946922805, 1.6094379124341, 3.17805383034795, 2.56494935746154, 
    2.19722457733622, 2.30258509299405, 2.484906649788, 3.52636052461616, 
    3.52636052461616, 3.58351893845611, NA, NA, 3.04452243772342, 
    2.07944154167984, 1.94591014905531, 2.07944154167984, 1.6094379124341, 
    3.46573590279973, 3.49650756146648, 3.17805383034795, NA, 
    NA, 3.52636052461616, 2.63905732961526, 2.484906649788, 2.83321334405622, 
    3.2188758248682, 3.40119738166216, 2.99573227355399, 2.30258509299405, 
    2.39789527279837, NA, 3.29583686600433, 3.36729582998647, 
    3.09104245335832, 2.94443897916644, 3.2188758248682, 3.58351893845611, 
    3.58351893845611, 1.94591014905531, 3.58351893845611, 3.04452243772342, 
    3.09104245335832, 3.17805383034795, 2.70805020110221, 3.43398720448515, 
    2.83321334405622, 3.40119738166216, 2.63905732961526, 2.39789527279837, 
    1.94591014905531, 2.19722457733622, 3.63758615972639, 3.49650756146648, 
    3.17805383034795, 3.13549421592915, 2.63905732961526, 3.3322045101752, 
    2.56494935746154, 1.38629436111989, 2.07944154167984, 2.19722457733622, 
    3.49650756146648, 3.17805383034795, 3.46573590279973, 2.07944154167984, 
    1.09861228866811, 3.36729582998647, 2.77258872223978, 0.693147180559945, 
    0.693147180559945, 1.6094379124341, 3.29583686600433, 1.6094379124341, 
    2.63905732961526, 1.09861228866811, 0.693147180559945, 3.58351893845611, 
    3.17805383034795, 3.09104245335832, 2.99573227355399, 3.13549421592915, 
    3.61091791264422, 3.36729582998647, 0.693147180559945, 3.09104245335832, 
    2.56494935746154, 3.29583686600433, 2.99573227355399, 2.99573227355399, 
    2.30258509299405, 2.39789527279837, 3.52636052461616, 2.70805020110221, 
    2.07944154167984, 1.94591014905531, 1.94591014905531, 3.43398720448515, 
    2.56494935746154, 3.17805383034795, 0, 0, 3.13549421592915, 
    2.83321334405622, 2.83321334405622, 1.09861228866811, 0, 
    3.46573590279973, 3.25809653802148, 3.17805383034795, 2.63905732961526, 
    2.94443897916644, 3.61091791264422, 2.83321334405622, 3.25809653802148, 
    2.484906649788, 2.99573227355399, 3.52636052461616, 3.55534806148941, 
    3.25809653802148, 3.36729582998647, 3.52636052461616, 3.46573590279973, 
    3.09104245335832, 3.61091791264422, 2.63905732961526, 2.484906649788, 
    3.3322045101752, 2.39789527279837, 2.63905732961526, 2.63905732961526, 
    2.63905732961526, 3.55534806148941, 3.55534806148941, 3.25809653802148, 
    3.3322045101752, 2.39789527279837, 3.52636052461616, 3.46573590279973, 
    2.63905732961526, NA, NA, 3.63758615972639, 3.58351893845611, 
    3.68887945411394, NA, NA, 3.71357206670431, 3.63758615972639, 
    2.94443897916644, NA, NA, 3.49650756146648, 3.13549421592915, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3.43398720448515, 3.29583686600433, 3.40119738166216, 
    NA, NA, 3.3322045101752, 3.04452243772342, NA, NA, NA), label = "HIV Test Value", format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -310L))
```

Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a simple plot a data. Based on your shown data, what exactly do you want to plot? And how is your data processed prior to the plotting?

Comment: I just want to reproduce the plot using R as the plot created by SPSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(condition, time) %>% 
  summarise(outcome = mean(outcome, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = outcome, color = as.factor(condition))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  ylab("Estimated Marginal Means") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Condition")
```

[image]